# Get latest row based on mutual timestamp column and action timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I retrieve most recently action timestamp row based on action timestamp (unique) and common timestamp (INDSTY_RPT_TMSTMP). The result should have only 1 row per INDSTY_RPT_TMSTMP row.

### Dataset:
[image]

### Expected result:
[image]

**Explanation**:

For this mutual timestamp (2020-08-11-18.55.15.100000) latest action is (2020-08-12-14.56.52.545822).

For this mutual timestamp (2020-08-11-18.50.15.100000) latest action is (2020-08-12-15.05.13.168624).

For this mutual timestamp (2020-08-11-18.45.15.100000) latest action is (2020-08-12-12.49.39.880529).

They are ordered by indsty_rpt_tmstmp desc, rpt_chg_tmstmp

I am trying with this but it is not working :

```
SELECT INDSTY_RPT_ID, INDSTY_RPT_ID_TP_CD, INDSTY_RPT_TMSTMP, max(RPT_CHG_TMSTMP),
INDSTY_RPT_STS_CD, INDSTY_RPT_STS_TP_CD, HTTP_RESP_CD, HTTP_RESP_DESC, APP_RESP_CD, APP_RESP_DESC 
FROM table
where indsty_rpt_id = 'Hfhs731'
group by INDSTY_RPT_ID, INDSTY_RPT_ID_TP_CD, INDSTY_RPT_TMSTMP, RPT_CHG_TMSTMP,
INDSTY_RPT_STS_CD, INDSTY_RPT_STS_TP_CD, HTTP_RESP_CD, HTTP_RESP_DESC, APP_RESP_CD, APP_RESP_DESC 
order by indsty_rpt_tmstmp desc, rpt_chg_tmstmp desc
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.rpt_chg_tmstmp = (select max(t2.rpt_chg_tmstmp)
                          from t t2
                          where t2.INDSTY_RPT_ID  = t.INDSTY_RPT_ID
```

and
t2.indsty_rpt_tmstmp = t.indsty_rpt_tmstmp
);

Comment: Thanks Gordon. You are a legend around here. One question: I want to get better at SQL, specifically hard ones like these. Any books / resources you recommend ?

Comment: Hi Gordon. I am trying out your way but it doesnt retreive 5th row in the result set. Query :SELECT INDSTY_RPT_ID, INDSTY_RPT_ID_TP_CD, INDSTY_RPT_TMSTMP, RPT_CHG_TMSTMP,
INDSTY_RPT_STS_CD, INDSTY_RPT_STS_TP_CD, HTTP_RESP_CD, HTTP_RESP_DESC, APP_RESP_CD, APP_RESP_DESC 
FROM PKN.INDSTY_RPT_HIST T1 WHERE 
T1.INDSTY_RPT_ID = 'Hfhs731' AND INDSTY_RPT_ID_TP_CD = 'PRN'  AND
T1.RPT_CHG_TMSTMP = 
(SELECT MAX(RPT_CHG_TMSTMP) FROM PKN.INDSTY_RPT_HIST T2 WHERE T1.INDSTY_RPT_TMSTMP = T2.INDSTY_RPT_TMSTMP)
ORDER BY  T1.indsty_rpt_tmstmp desc, T1.rpt_chg_tmstmp desc

Comment: If you are filtering per report then you also need a condition on the report.  That wasn't in your original question.

Comment: @testdummy . . . This is not a site to recommend books.  Of course, I recommend books that I have written myself.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 8.0+ you can use a window function to assign a sequential number sorted by the timestamp in descending order and select the most recent. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY indsty_rpt_tmstmp ORDER BY rpt_chg_tmstmp DESC) AS row_num
  FROM t
  
) t1
WHERE row_num = 1
```